# JpaRepository findLast20 doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Method in my JpaRepository fetches all users except the last 20:

```
List<User> findLast20ByOrderById();
```

If I replace Last to Top, it fetches the first 20 users.
I have to fetch the last 20 users, no matter ordered by id or not.

Comment: What do you mean "last 20 users" if there is no sort? What does "last" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring data jpa documentation :

> The results of query methods can be limited via the keywords first or
>   top, which can be used interchangeably. An optional numeric value can
>   be appended to top/first to specify the maximum result size to be
>   returned. If the number is left out, a result size of 1 is assumed.

You can use order direction asc or desc

```
findFirst20ByOrderByIdDesc();
```

**EDIT** : Last keyword will not work

```
findLast20ByOrderByIdAsc();
```

Comment: Didn't tested with First, but Last returns all users.

Comment: Spring data jpa documentation states that you can just use first/top there is no last keyword http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result